# A way to alter GetFormData code to search subfolders

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been using the getformdata code (below) to collate data from VBA Word Forms, but I would love to know if it's possible to alter the code so I can select a higher folder and it will search all subfolders.

```
Sub GetFormData()
     'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim FmFld As Word.FormField
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
    strFolder = GetFolder
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
    i = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
        i = i + 1
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" &     strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
        With wdDoc
            j = 0
            For Each FmFld In .FormFields
                j = j + 1
                WkSht.Cells(i, j) = FmFld.Result
            Next
        End With
        wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
```

I have found code that looks at subfolders, but it seems to be a sub in itself and I don't know where in relation to this I could use it.  Thanks.

Comment: Look at using the FileSystemObject, there you can set the top folder and then look at the .SubFolders

Comment: Thanks, I tried reading about FileSystemObject and found code for it, but if I put it before my above code nothing happens.  Have you any more specific advice?

Comment: Look at looping subfolders using filesystemobject